# How to set a circular FAB button

Tags: android, floating-action-button

[image]I am trying to set a circular fab button which on clicked display other options in a circular but I am getting some error on setting the setImageDrawable
I am using compile time dependency
 compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2' my java code is

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionMenu;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.SubActionButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            ImageView itemIcon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + step-forward, null, null);
            itemIcon.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.button_action);
            SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon).build();

        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addSubActionView(button1)

                .attachTo(fab)
                .build();}
    });
}
```

}
What changes will i do to make the sub action button work
and when I use

```
 ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
icon.setImageDrawable( ... );
FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
.setContentView(icon)
.build();`
```

in place of 
     `final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {`

declaring the fab button i get error in build
WHEN i used only one source  like this

```
 ImageView icon = new ImageView(this); // Create an icon
            icon.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.step_forward );
            FloatingActionButton actionButton = new     FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                    .setContentView(icon)
                    .build();
            SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new   SubActionButton.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            ImageView itemIcon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + step-forward, null, null);
            itemIcon.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.button_action);
            SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon).build();

        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addSubActionView(button1)

                .attachTo(actionButton)
                .build();}
```

I am getting error in setting the Builder in    FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
and error on setting the setImageDrawable

Comment: you are importing fab from two places from support library as well as well as your third party library. Remove one that is not required

Comment: still I am getting error bro

Comment: which one you removed?

Comment: and imported one from library?

Comment: your import should look like this now `import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionButton;`

Comment: no I have deleated the fab that is given by android studio

Comment: import the one I told jsut now

Comment: ya i have imported that

Comment: now run it should not give error now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109588/discussion-between-neelay-srivastava-and-vivek-mishra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FloatingActionButton` I tried to use is from the `com.android.support:design` which doesn't have the `Builder()` method.

You need to use the `FloatingActionButton` from  `com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu`.

Remove import `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;` and add

`import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionButton;`
wherever you want to use com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu's `FloatingActionButton`